# python rolling 3 dice

Tags: python, random, dice

The task is: throw three dice and sum their results. Run that function 10 thousand times and compute the average and the standard deviation of the results.

My question is: I wrote the code and get 10000 sum as 'b'. Now, I need to sum them and take the average. I do not know how to proceed.

```
import random

rolls = 10000; #rolling 10000 times
for i in range(0, rolls):
    die1 = random.randint(1,6)
    die2 = random.randint(1,6)
    die3= random.randint(1,6)
    a=[die1, die2 ,die3]
    b=sum(a)
    print(b)
```

Comment: How would you calculate an average on paper? What difficulties do you have transferring this "algorithm" to Python?

Answer (score 2):

You should have another variable to sum all of the b's together, then divide that variable by your amount of rolls:

```
import random

rolls = 10000 #rolling 10000 times
totalSum = 0
for i in range(0, rolls):
    die1 = random.randint(1,6)
    die2 = random.randint(1,6)
    die3= random.randint(1,6)
    a=[die1, die2 ,die3]
    b=sum(a)
    totalSum += b
    print(b)

average = totalSum / rolls
```

Now you should be able to solve the rest of your question.

Comment: in order to do the rest he is prob going to need a list of all the outcomes of the 3 dice

Comment: True, but this answer should have given him enough insight in what to do next, as the code already contains almost the whole answer.

Comment: @vash_the_stampede No, you need the sum of the values, the sum of their squares, and the count to calculate average and std deviation.  You don't need to retain all the values.

Comment: @pjs inst it the sqrt of the variance ? and isnt variance the average of (score-mean) squared for all the scores

Comment: @vash_the_stampede `Sum{(x_i - x_bar)^2} = Sum{x_i^2} - n * x_bar^2`.  That allows you to do it in one pass.

Comment: @pjs my math skills :(, I understand now

Comment: @vash_the_stampede I was just looking for a link to it.  Surprisingly hard to find, given that it's in pretty much every stats text out there.   It's algebraically an identity, and uses less storage and less time to compute.  See the middle portion of first formula in [this Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance).

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to forgo a loop based approach you really should use the multinomial distribution which simulates your scenario in a vectorised manner...

```
import numpy as np
die = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
tally = np.sum(np.random.multinomial(3, [1/6]*6, size=10000) * die, axis=1)
np.mean(tally)
# 10.469
np.std(tally)
# 2.974
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

numdice = 3
numRolls = 10000 

rollSums = []
for i in range(0, numRolls):
    for d in range(0, numDice):
        sum = float(random.randint(1, 6))
    totalSum += sum
    rollSums.append(sum)

average = sum / numRolls

print(average)
```

Comment: This will give the correct average, but doesn't set up for calculating std deviation.

Answer (score 0):

The following does the setup so you can calculate both the average and sample standard deviation.  You can calculate std dev by leveraging the algebraic relationship Σ(x<sub>i</sub> - x<sub>bar</sub>)<sup>2</sup> = Σx<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> - n * x<sub>bar</sub><sup>2</sup>.

This implementation can easily be modified to do different numbers of rolls and different numbers of dice.

```
import random

rolls = 10000  #rolling 10000 times
num_dice = 3

sum = 0.0
sum_sq = 0.0

for i in range(rolls):
    die_sum = 0.0
    for j in range(num_dice):
        die_sum += random.randint(1,6)
    sum += die_sum
    sum_sq += die_sum * die_sum
    # I don't actually recommend printing the following unless you like
    # seeing 10k random numbers stream to your console
    # print(die_sum)

# You're now set up to calculate the average and standard deviation
# using sum, sum_sq, and rolls.
print(sum / rolls)   # the average
# Leaving std deviation to you, but all the pieces are here now.
```